# Having trouble setting DevExpress CheckEdit.EditValue to True. EditValue remains as Nothing even when assigning a value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, devexpress

I have an Xtra Tab Control which contains 6 tab pages. On each of these tab pages lives a User Control which contains a Check Edit on a Binding Navigator that I want to default to checked when creating the form as shown below (worth noting that I am using a library for the Binding Navigator and this code cannot be changed):

[image]

To do this I thought I'd be fine putting the code in the Initialise method of the User Control so when creating the User Control for each of these tabs I'd be able to set the EditValue to True but unfortunately even when assigning the EditValue to True the EditValue just remains as Nothing (Indeterminate)

[image]

I've managed to get the check edit on the first User Control to set by default by using the UserControl_Loaded event, however, for the other 5 tabs the value is not checked as the Loaded event hasn't fired for these yet until the tab is selected.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the tabpages to load them